# Set up a Windows 10 library that acts like a folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am moving to a new laptop, and want to create a library that acts like the one I created on my old laptop, but don't remember how I did it any more.

- Instructions say to navigate to *Libraries* and choose the option to create a new library; after doing so, I see hints to *add folders*, but when I add a folder, and open the library in Explorer, the top of the right-hand main pane display shows:

  - the name of the folder I added, followed by a horizontal line stretching across that pane
  - the full path of the folder containing the named folder
  - files and folders in that folder
- If I add other folders, each one gets another name + horizontal line, location, etc.

On my current computer, I have a library named `files`, and it does not have any of the horizontal line or location string -- it just looks like a regular Windows folder, and shows files and folders from ONE Windows folder [`%UserProfile%\files`]; if I added files/directories to `%UserProfile%\files`, they show up in the library.

I would like to create another library like that one, mirroring a folder, but which shows up in the *Libraries* section of Explorer so that it is pinned there. How do I create a library that behaves like that?

Comment: Windows 10 File Explorer, View, Navigation Pane:  Show Libraries.

Comment: That shows libraries; I was asking how to create one that didn't 'section' the main display pane for each folder in the library, that in fact looks just like a folder.

Comment: @rcook Are you certain the old laptop had a library for `files` and it wasn't just a folder added to the Navigation pane via the Registry? AFAIK, a library will always show as described, however I've never used a custom library with only one folder, since the purpose of a library is to aggregate data from two or more locations. If the View settings or editing the `.library-ms` file doesnt result in the old PC's appearance you describe, [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/windows-libraries) may help _(I'm not on a PC at the moment)_.

Comment: When you right-click in the background of your existing "FIles" Library, does it have the `Arrange by >` entry in the context menu? If so, What is selected?

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, quite certain. I would never have set up a library that way, and I do remember creating this library. I wanted a directory subtree that was easily accessible; some strange part of my brain objects to thinking of "Documents" as the top of that tree, and I wanted to see it as a 'library' when I opened file explorer. I may substitute a folder pinned to 'quick access', but that's not what this is either.

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, it has `Arrange By >`, and `Folder` is selected. I created a test library on this machine and put a folder in it; it has the same `Arrange By >` option selected, and shows the name of the folder in the main pane, though my 'files' library does not.

Comment: @JW0914 Hunted down the `.library-ms` for the `files` and the `testLib` libraries I'd created; `files` has a `version` of 7, `testLib` has 17; `folderType` is 0s for `files` and a long string of hex digits for `testLib`. I don't remember seeing `library-ms` files before, but I might have forgotten. I'll dig into this further, thanks.

Comment: @rcook Kieth's suggestion of _Arrange By_ seems to be the issue, as once something other than _Folder_ is selected, it displays without the horizontal line and location path, and leaving it on _Folder_, but changing the _Group By_ option will also result in the same

Comment: Yep. Like SearchResults (as Librarires are essentially a saved search), the default grouping is on a property *not selectaabel through the UI*. So if you set grouping to `(None)` when `Arrange by >` is set to folder, you see the folders & files of the source folder(s) with no grouping. That's probably what you did with your `Files` Library, as the grouping is redundant if the source is a single folder.